# button visible is all checkbox is true

Tags: java, android

I am new with android usually I develop for windows platform with powershell.

I am trying to find a way to make the button visible if all checkbox are tik .

I tried so many code from google but still doesn't work so which parts I miss ?

[I put all file because I got no ideas which one you will need](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=kZcynFVZ4pP6hOIhpSYbhLr4qNLgU7nbiD5V)
You can directly edit on it should to work

Thank you for your help and times
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLDISZ-FXWo

```
    package com.example.checkbox;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    private CheckBox ch1,ch2,ch3, ch4 ;
    private button btnSubmit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();

        btnSubmit.setOnclickListnener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void OnClick(View View) {

                StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
                result.append("gold:\n");
                if (ch1.isChecked()){
                    result.append(ch1.getText().toString()).append("\n");
                }
                if (ch2.isChecked()){
                    result.append(ch2.getText().toString()).append("\n");
                }
                if (ch3.isChecked()){
                    result.append(ch3.getText().toString()).append("\n");
                }
                if (ch4.isChecked()){
                    result.append(ch4.getText().toString()).append("\n");
                }
                Toast.makeText( context: MainActivity.this,
                                result,toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        });

    }


    Private void init(){
        Ch1=findViewById(R.id.Check_pump);
        Ch2=findViewById(R.id.Check_GPS);
        Ch3=findViewById(R.id.carbone_arms);
        ch4=findViewById(R.id.Check_battery);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener listener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        if(cb1.isChecked() && cb2.isChecked() && cb3.isChecked() && cb4.isChecked())
            btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
};
```

Do something like this. Add the above listner to all of your checkboxes like below:-

```
    cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
    cb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
    cb3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
    cb4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
```

Also, please do not forget to initialize your button as well.